# Rust: How to concatenate bytes together

Tags: rust

I have already read the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893216/how-to-concatenate-static-arrays-in-rust) but still get some errors with my current attempt:

```rs
let data = &[37u8, 42u8];
let data_two = &[0x34u8, 0x32u8];
let res:Vec<u8> = [data, data_two].concat();
```

---

Also, ideally I would like to avoid concatenation, and write an array of u8 to a buffer, where I reserve the first two bytes for storing length and index like:

```rs
let nb:u8 = get_chunks_nb();
let index:u8 = get_chunk_index();
let header = &[nb, index];

// this kind of things in C:
memcpy(&buffer, header, 2);
memcpy(&buffer[2], chunk, chunk_len);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a shot at it, but I'm not 100% sure as to why, I'm still new to Rust.

It looks like the compiler is seeing `data` and `data_two` as arrays, and so `[data, data_two]` is then an array of array and not an array of slice. Which is probably why it couldn't find the `concat` method on it.

By explicitely saying that data is a slice, everything seems to fall into place:

```
let data:&[u8] = &[37u8, 42u8];
let data_two = &[0x34u8, 0x32u8];
let mut res:Vec<u8> = [data, data_two].concat();
```

Comment: Your suspicion is correct: `Concat` for `[V]` [relies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.Concat.html#impl-Concat%3CT%3E) on `V: Borrow<[T]>` and, because the elements of the array (the `V`s) are `&[u8; 2]`, they do not implement `Borrow<[u8]>`. If you dereference them (`[*data, *data_two].concat()`) it works, because `[u8; 2]` *does* implement `Borrow<[u8]>` (this is not necessarily the best idea, because it copies the contents). Similarly, if you coerce `data` to a slice reference (`[data as &[_], data_two].concat()`), it also works because `&[u8]` also implements `Borrow<[u8]>`.

Comment: @trentcl Thank you for the explanation! I don't understand your comment on copying the content though, wouldn't it copy in any case?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution @ShadowMitia, works like a charm.

Comment: `[data, data_two]` is an array of references, but `[*data, *data_two]` is an array of arrays, so the content from the arrays has to be copied into the bigger array *before* you actually call `.concat()` on it, which will copy the contents *again*. So it might make the difference between one copy and two. In such a trivial case as this it's likely that compiler optimizations make the difference irrelevant.

Comment: what would be your suggestion @trentcl to avoid the copy ?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL I'd probably use `[data as &[_], data_two].concat()` (coercing the reference doesn't need to copy the contents) or I guess `[data.as_ref(), data_two]` would work as well.